# Linux Server Can't Run ASP.NET using dotnet Command

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, .net-core, coreclr

I installed **`.NET 7.0.3`** on my Linux Server.

I also deployed a few MVC websites in **`.NET 7.0.0`** behind an Apache reverse proxy.

But when I run `dotnet <DLL NAME>.dll`, It is saying it can't find a framework

[image]

If I check the install status, I can see it is properly installed

[image]

The fun thing is, While I was unable to run any of my ASP.NET Core app using `dotnet <DLL NAME>.dll` command,

If I hit URL in a browser, Apache is able to proxy to it and I can see the website content. Why this is happening?

## Here's a VIDEO DEMONSTRATION

YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJkIasUPWzU

Comment: Install .NET SDK to.

Answer (score 1):

You have the .NET CLI installed, but that's not the only thing you need to run .NET binaries.

`dotnet --info` is telling us you don't have any runtimes or SDKs installed. At a minimum you need to install the .NET 7.0.0 Runtime using the link provided to you in the error message: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64

Comment: I have aspnetcore 7.0.3 runtime installed

Comment: Updated with new image after I installed whole SDK which includes runtime as well

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is not the .net core runtime. It is a metadata package for .net core runtime libraries. So you are missing actual runtime library which should called `Microsoft.NETCore.App`.

When you run the the `dotnet --list-runtimes` you need to see following output. In your case only the first one (metadata package) will be available.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

So you need to install correct runtime package from [here microsoft .net platform](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0)

Comment: I understood the point Teoman. But then how my existing websites works?

Comment: Attached a video demonstration to the question for brevity and all details

Comment: sdk and runtime both can run dotnet application. I believe you are running existing websites through sdk. But since you want to run your application over runtime with dotnet api.dll you must install curresponding runtime. Also it is not convenient to run application on production with sdk. It is only for development. In the production always use runtimes.